# Hadoop: Unable to run mapreduce program ..java.io.IOException: error=12

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Im trying to run a mapreduce program in hadoop. Basically it takes in a text file as input in which each line is a json text. Im using simple json to parse this data in my mapper and the reducer does some other stuff. I have included the simple json jar file in hadoop/lib folder.  here is the code below

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class ALoc
{
    public static class AMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        private Text kword = new Text();
        private Text vword = new Text();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            try {
                String line = value.toString();
                Object obj = parser.parse(line);

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                String val = (String)jsonObject.get("m1") + "," + (String)jsonObject.get("m3");
                kword.set((String)jsonObject.get("m0"));
                vword.set(val);
                context.write(kword, vword);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }              
        }
    }

    public static class CountryReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        private Text result = new Text();
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
        Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int ccount = 0;
            HashMap<Text, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Text, Integer>();

            for (Text val : values)
            {
                if(hm.containsKey(val)){
                        Integer n = (Integer)hm.get(val);
                        hm.put(val, n+1);
                }else{
                        hm.put(val, new Integer(1));
                }
            }
            Set set = hm.entrySet();
            Iterator i = set.iterator();
            String agr = "";

            while(i.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
                agr += "|" + me.getKey() + me.getValue();
            }
            result.set(agr);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "ALoc");
        job.setJarByClass(ALoc.class);
        job.setMapperClass(AMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CountryReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the job. It gives the following error. 
I am running this in a aws micro instance single node.
I have been following this tutorial http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

```
    hadoop@domU-18-11-19-02-92-8E:/$ bin/hadoop jar ALoc.jar org.myorg.ALoc /user/hadoop/adata /user/hadoop/adata-op5 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=16
13/02/12 08:39:50 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/02/12 08:39:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/02/12 08:39:50 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/02/12 08:39:50 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/02/12 08:39:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201302120714_0006
13/02/12 08:39:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/02/12 08:40:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302120714_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/ls": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.obtainLogDirOwner(TaskLog.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater.truncateLogs(TaskLogsTruncater.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    ... 15 more

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.obtainLogDirOwner(TaskLog.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater.truncateLogs(TaskLogsTruncater.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must be trying hadoop on Micro instance which have very less memory (~700MB).

Try increasing the HADOOP Heapsize parameter (in hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh) .. as the basic reason is shortage of memory required to fork processes